# Let user outside of my 365 edit files on my sharepoint?

Tags: office-365, external-users

I have a budget, made in excel, I have a 365 business and a team site used as document library.

Can I somehow let other users log in with "normal" emails and use these files, or are they prohibited from taking part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Once you’re logged into your Office 365 OneDrive account, just click the ellipses (…) next to the document of your choice to open up the options window and then click Share.

[image]

2. Next a share dialog box will come up, click on Get a link.

[image]

3. Then select Create a link for the type of permission you want to grant. To create a guest link simply click the View Only option; this will allow external users to open up and read documents without the editing permissions.

[image]

4. Select and copy the guest link URL then paste to the chosen media you wish to share it with. This can either be done through an email or even a social media page.

[image]

http://responza.com/blog/2014/productivity/office-365-onedrive-how-to-share-documents-with-external-users/

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Share-sites-or-documents-with-people-outside-your-organization-80e49744-e30f-44db-8d51-16661b1d4232

Comment: Please up-vote this answer so that it can be helpful to others.

Comment: I can mark it as anwser - I don't have rep enough to upvote sir :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can share sites externally with people not affiliated with your tenant/domain in Office 365. It has to be allowed by your global administrators and your site collection has to be enabled for it.

You simply share the site, library, or file with an external email address. That user will get a notification that it has been shared with them. Depending on the sharing configuration of the tenant, they will either have anonymous access to the shared item or be required to log in with an existing O365 account or Microsoft account.